# How to isolate a single game from a pgn file containing multiple games in python?

Tags: python, python-chess

I have a pgn file with multiple games. I want to separate all the games into different files or just one text file so that I can separate all the White moves and Black moves. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your file looks like this:

[Event "Llyods Bank"]
[...]

1.e4 [...]

[Event "Lloyds Bank"]
[...]

1.e4 [...]

Then, a simple approach would be to append to the list all the lines until you find the 2nd '\n'

Here's a naive piece of code:

```
from os import read


my_file = open("Adams.pgn", "r")
content_list = my_file. readlines()
print(content_list)

list_games = []
game = []
j = 0
for i in content_list:
    if i == "\n":
        j += 1
    if j == 2:
        j = 0
        list_games.append(game)
        game = []
    game.append(i)
if game.empty() == False:
    list_games.append(game)

for i in game:
    print(game)
```

Comment: We get this error when performing any normal read, write operations
 
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x82 in position 1891: invalid start byte

Comment: Try this: 

my_file = open("Adams.pgn", "r", errors="ignore")

Please give us a glimpse of what your file looks like